# bar chart race axis formating

Tags: python

I have three columns in my dataset. 'Initial condition', 'Probability of A occurring given initial condition' and 'Probability of B occurring given initial condition'. I want a bar chart race animation gif in Python where I can show the progression of the bars (representing Probability of A and B) with changing initial condition. I tried doing this but the x-axis representing the values of the bar is either 0 or 1. I am unable to format it so that it gets shown in two decimal places. Would be really helpful if anyone can assist me. Here is the data sample.

[image]

Here is the code I used.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bar_chart_race as bcr

# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Set the index to the starting capital of A
data = data.set_index('Initial captial of A')

# Create the animated bar chart race
bcr.bar_chart_race(
    df=data,
    filename='race.gif',
    orientation='h',
    sort='desc',
    n_bars=3,
    steps_per_period=10,
    interpolate_period=False,
    label_bars=True,
    bar_size=.95,
    period_length=500,
    figsize=(6, 3),
    dpi=144,
    title='Race',
    writer='pillow'
)

plt.show()
```

Comment: please add an excerpt of the content of data.csv

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I have added the data sample. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you have to set up manually the x-ticks using `ax.set_xticks()` from matplotlib package.

Here is a code snippet to show you the idea with dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bar_chart_race as bcr
import numpy as np
# Load the data
# data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
N = 20
data = pd.DataFrame({'Initial captial of A': np.arange(N),
                     'Probability_A': np.linspace(0, 1, N),
                     'Probability B': np.linspace(1, 0, N)})
# Set the index to the starting capital of A
data = data.set_index('Initial captial of A')
print(data.head())

# Create the animated bar chart race
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 4), dpi=120, tight_layout=True)
bcr.bar_chart_race(
    df=data,
    filename='race.gif',
    orientation='h',
    sort='desc',
    n_bars=3,
    steps_per_period=1,
    interpolate_period=True,
    label_bars=True,
    bar_size=.95,
    period_length=1,
    dpi=144,
    fig=fig,
    title='Race',
    writer='pillow',
    fixed_max=True,
    fixed_order=['Probability_A', 'Probability B']
)
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
plt.show()
```

Let me know if you have further questions.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I will post this as an answer, as it might get lost as a comment:

The amount of decimal places for the bar labels is hard-coded to zero in the current version 0.1.0 of the package. The latest version 0.2.0 of bar_chart_race is not available via PIP yet, but can be installed in other ways (see this [github issue answer](https://github.com/dexplo/bar_chart_race/issues/26#issuecomment-988822576)):

Terminal:

```
pip uninstall bar_chart_race
pip install git+https://github.com/dexplo/bar_chart_race
```

With this latest version, you can add the keyword `bar_texttemplate='{x:,.2f}'` to get two decimal places (but some other keywords like "label_bars" and "dpi" have to be removed). Same goes for the xtick-labels via `tick_template="{x:,.2f}"`:

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bar_chart_race as bcr
import numpy as np

N = 20
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Initial captial of A": np.arange(N),
        "Probability_A": np.linspace(0, 1, N),
        "Probability B": np.linspace(1, 0, N),
    }
)
# Set the index to the starting capital of A
data = data.set_index("Initial captial of A")

# Create the animated bar chart race
bcr.bar_chart_race(
    df=data,
    filename="race.gif",
    interpolate_period=True,
    writer="pillow",
    fixed_max=True,
    bar_texttemplate="{x:,.2f}",
    tick_template="{x:,.2f}",
)
```