# Unexpected keyword argument bar_texttemplate for bar_chart_race

Tags: python

I am trying to animate my bar chart in python using the bar_chart_race with bar_texttemplate to give me an animated chart to 2 decimal places but it was throwing `TypeError: bar_chart_race() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bar_texttemplate'`.

I have read and followed similar question in this thread [bar chart race axis formating using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75923265/bar-chart-race-axis-formating-using-python) but all to no avail.

I meant, I uninstalled the initial bar_chart_race and installed the recommended package but I still have the error.
This is the version I have installed : bar-chart-race-0.2.0

This is my code:

```
bcr.bar_chart_race(
   df = df,
   bar_texttemplate='{x:,.2f}',
   period_summary_func=func,
   title = "xxxx",
   sort='desc',
   figsize=(5,3))
```

In addition, when I called the bar_chart_race function this is what shows up:

```
def bar_chart_race(
    df: Any,
    filename: Any | None = None,
    orientation: str = 'h',
    sort: str = 'desc',
    n_bars: Any | None = None,
    fixed_order: bool = False,
    fixed_max: bool = False,
    steps_per_period: int = 10,
    period_length: int = 500,
    interpolate_period: bool = False,
    label_bars: bool = True,
    bar_size: float = 0.95,
    period_label: bool = True,
    period_fmt: Any | None = None,
    period_summary_func: Any | None = None,
    perpendicular_bar_func: Any | None = None,
    figsize: Any = (6, 3.5),
    cmap: Any | None = None,
    title: Any | None = None,
    title_size: Any | None = None,
    bar_label_size: int = 7,
    tick_label_size: int = 7,
    shared_fontdict: Any | None = None,
    scale: str = 'linear',
    writer: Any | None = None,
    fig: Any | None = None,
    dpi: int = 144,
    bar_kwargs: Any | None = None,
    filter_column_colors: bool = False
)
```

It appears that `bar_texttemplate` and `tick_template` do not seem to be in the function.

How else can I adjust the decimal places?

I have tried changing some of the arguments of the function but it wasn't working as expected.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for asking the question. I saw `tick_template` and 0.2.0 recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77147507). Could I check if you've read the [documentation](https://www.dexplo.org/bar_chart_race/) for the `bar_chart_race` module already?

Comment: Yes, I have read it, is there a particular thing you want to draw my attention to? I will appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77147507) which recommends installing bar_chart_race 0.2.0 via git+https. As of February 2024, it is still not available via pip. The install command is reproduced here for convenience:

```
pip uninstall bar_chart_race
pip install git+https://github.com/dexplo/bar_chart_race
```

Once this is done, I tried a simplified version of the data as `test.csv`:

```
start,p(B),p(A)
1,0.05,0.95
2,0.1,0.9
3,0.15,0.85
4,0.2,0.8
```

Then I adapted the following code from the other question:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bar_chart_race as bcr
 
# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# Set the index to the starting capital of A
data = data.set_index('start')

# Create the animated bar chart race
bcr.bar_chart_race(
    df=data,
    filename='race.gif',
    orientation='h',
    sort='desc',
    n_bars=3,
    steps_per_period=10,
    interpolate_period=False,
    bar_size=.95,
    period_length=500,
    title='Race',
    writer='pillow',
    bar_texttemplate="{x:,.2f}",
    tick_template="{x:,.2f}"
)

plt.show()
```

Note that some of the arguments in the original call were no longer needed in this version, so I removed them, and this is what I got.

[image: race.gif with ticks to two decimal places]

Comment: When I repeated your code, I got the same error message 'bar_chart_race() got an unexpected keyword argument bar_texttemplate'. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you for trying my code! Are you certain the version of `bar_chart_race()` is 0.2.0? Please try the code from my [github repo](https://github.com/icedwater/so_random/), I have tested it before pushing. I'll check that code again myself in a few hours and update here.

Comment: Yes, I tried your code and is giving me the same error. The version is 0.2.0
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
---> 16 bcr.bar_chart_race(
     17     df=data,
     18     filename='race.gif',
     19     orientation='h',
     20     sort='desc',
     27     writer='pillow',
     28     bar_texttemplate="{x:,.2f}",
     29     tick_template="{x:,.2f}"
     30 )
     32 plt.show()

TypeError: bar_chart_race() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bar_texttemplate'

Comment: This is the output I got when I tried to check the version : Name: bar-chart-race
Version: 0.2.0
Summary: Create animated bar chart races using matplotlib or plotly

Comment: Hi there - I've checked my code on a new computer by cloning the repo into a folder, entering the `bar_chart_race/` subfolder, and creating a virtual environment. After activating that venv, I installed `bar_chart_race==0.2.0` using `pip install -r requirements.txt` - this "clean install" works. Please let me know if those steps also work for you; I'll add a README to that subfolder. If you join **#stackoverflow** on [Libera Chat](https://web.libera.chat) we can talk there, it should be faster.

Comment: You're very welcome - may I know what the last missing piece was, please? If you prefer to tell me privately, I'll be at Libera Chat :)

Comment: pip install -r requirements.txt was the only missing item. In addition, if you include the fig size, it would not work. I am not sure why. Although, I'm okay with what I have now as everything seems to work fine.